# Переполнение массива. Язык си

Tags: c, массивы, переполнение

Объявить двумерный массив размера 7Х8, заполнить его случайными числами.
Вывести значения массива на экран в виде таблицы. Найти сумму элементов
массива, сумма индексов которых равна 10.

Вот в чем проблема когда объявляю массив 7Х8, выскакивает ошибка: "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'A' was corrupted."
А когда задаю массив чуть больше к примеру 25Х25, то все работает прекрасно.

Вот собственно сам код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int A[7][8];
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            **(A + i + j) = rand() % 100;
            printf("%2.d ", **(A + i + j));
            if (i + j == 10)
                sum += **(A + i + j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("%d", sum);
    _getch;
}
```

Comment: Что за... `**(A + i + j)`? Работайте с `A[i][j]`, зачем эти (неверные) обращения?

Comment: И, кстати, если уж использовать `_getch;`, то так: `_getch();` :) И еще - зачем у вас точка в `%2.d`? что вы хотите ею добиться?

Answer (score 5):

Словом, или обращайтесь к `A[i][j]`, или работайте с указателями правильно:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        *(*(A + i) + j) = rand() % 100;
        printf("%2d ", *(*(A + i) + j));
        if (i + j == 10)
            sum += *(*(A + i) + j);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Update** для сомневающихся. Набирать лень, так что просто кусок стандарта C картинкой...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `*(*(A + i) + j)` там же не вложенный массив..

Comment: @Harry Эм.. А это точно правильно?

Comment: @pavel https://ideone.com/ycabp0

Comment: @pavel `int A[7][8];` - это массив массивов. Вполне вложенный. :)

Comment: Хм... я думал что a[7][8] и a[56] это одно и тоже...

Comment: @pavel, по идее ты прав.

Comment: @Qwertiy Не по идее, а по размеру :)

Comment: @pavel Примерно так - A - указатель на строки (ну, типа, `int A[][8]`), так что `A+i` - указатель на `i`-ю строку. `*(A+i)` - сама эта `i`-я строка, `int[8]`, так что `*(A+i)+j` - указатель на `j`-й элемент `i`-й строки... Убедил? :)

Comment: @pavel См. дополнение в ответе. Особенно пример мелким шрифтом.

Comment: @Qwertiy См. дополнение в ответе. Особенно пример мелким шрифтом.